# build screen recorder with expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

how can I build a screen recorder with expo react native. I want the screen recorder to capture whatever comes on the users screen except of any sensitive data ofcourse and then after recording is stopped by the user, it must convert the entire recording into a video and place it in the users view or basically show the video in the expo app. Another question is, will it be possible to make the screen recorder capture only one specific app while making the screen go black if the user switches to another app while recording?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is possible in expo. Because if you leave the app to another app or just go to your home. All the codes in your expo app will stop running in the background. These are some codes that can run at background. But this kind of task most probably not possible with expo.